# F12 key in SDL causes breakpoint?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl

I have recently taken two SDL projects - a demo project, and one of my own and compiled with SDL under VC++ 6.0. In Debug configuration, I can get all key presses fine with the exception of the F12 key. If I press F12, I get a "user breakpoint" in NTDLL, no matter what.

Has anybody else experienced this or able to help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

:-) The reason this happened was that I was running my app in Debug configuration.. and after 9 years I had no idea that the F12 key causes a break to occur within MSVC.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know either. I thought it was crashing